# Different wrapper background-images wordpress custom template

Tags: php, css, wordpress, templates, wrapper

I need to load different background-images for the wrapper of my custom template, i need one in index.php, archive.php and in single.php.

I tried making a different div, but it doesn't works because index, archive and single inherit the header.php, which is where the wrapper div is...

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not awrae about WordPress but if you are having issue of inheriting, you can provide stronger rules in your stylesheet

```
.classname element {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

On the other hand you can also use `!important` declaration(Which I won't prefer using unless and until required)

Comment: Thank you very much, but i need something more of an override for the original wrapper just for index.php, archive.php and single.php

Comment: @user2089267 Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I can provide these pastebins [Header](http://pastebin.com/ZgdZuFca) The line of interest in this one is line 34, [css](http://pastebin.com/GK3rLU16) line 196 in this css, [single](http://pastebin.com/b6GhATJ9) and line 1 in this single.php, so i need this wrapper to remain where it is, but at the same time, need to override it just for index, archive and single.php

Comment: Adding another background in the same wrapper class using !important you mean?

Comment: @user2089267 If you add another background in the same class, it will be override the old one automatically :)

Comment: I know !important can override, but i mean, i don't need to replace the background-image in a permanent way :(, just in two cases, are you sure?

Comment: @user2089267 Actually your requirement is bouncing over my head, as overriding should be very simple

Comment: Sorry i'm maybe not explaining myself :(, i know is very easy, but wordpress loads wrapper classes in header.php (in my case) then calls it from the other blog sections, i need a div or a php code to override the wrapper declared in header, but not completely override it, as it is doing right now with !important, but just for two sections, and these two sections will have a different background each... of course !important can override, but it's not like just overriding completely an html or a single div, sorry :(